# Fiware error on creating service and registration for a device

Tags: fiware, iota

i am a fiware user and i have created an iot agent on an ubuntu 14.04 empty vm and when i send a create service or a device registration request ,  i get an error. And i've made sure that the ports listen properly and i've also allowed tcp connection on the port 4061. and also get an error whenever i send the request .

here's the create service request

```
(curl -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'fiware-service: bla770' -H 'fiware-servicepath: /howtobla770' -X POST 'http://217.172.12.243:4061/iot/services' -d @- ) << EOF
{
    "services": [
        {
            "apikey": "api70",
            "token": "token",
            "cbroker": "http://147.27.60.58:1026",
            "resource": "/iot/d",
            "entity_type": "thing"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

and this is the error which i get .

```
connect to 217.172.12.243 port 4061 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to 217.172.12.243 port 4061: Connection timed out
```

Although i have allowed  the port 4061 through the firewall by the command 
sudo ufw allow 4061

```
sudo ufw allow 4061
```

So, what could be done to solve this error please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i  think  you can solve this  by deploy preconfigured image like Cepheus and it will allow you  to use port**8080** and **8081** and you can  configure your iot agent to listen by change in **config.js** file